# How to use the command "+incdir+" in synplify script(.tcl) when one verilog file include another verilog file?

Tags: verilog, fpga, vivado, synthesis, synplify

I insert a verilog file into another verilog file by using "`include "
And when I used the synplify script(*.tcl) to try to synthesize, one error occured:

```
invalid command name "+incdir+<...>"
```

It seems like I have to use the command "+incdir+" according to online documents, but what something wrong happened?

[Example page 365](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/132975-synopsys-fpga-synthesis-synplify-pro-me-g2012-09a-sp4-user-guide)

```
If your project has Verilog files with `include statements, you must use
the +incdir+ <file name> argument when you specify the vlogan
command. You enter the +incdir+ in the Verilog Compile field in the VCS
Options dialog box, as shown below:
```

Comment: +incdir+ does not include anything. It only specifies directories where compile looks for files from `include statements. Other than that you should provide more info about your issues.

Answer (score -1):

quoting from the documentation : if you have an include file,

```
`include "component.v"
module Top (input a, output x);
...
endmodule
```

you need to tell the relative directory of the include file (component.v) with respect to the directory of synplify script(.tcl) :

```
vlogan -work work Top.v +incdir+ ./ +incdir+ ../include_dir1
```

etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).